# Changing the location of the busyIndicator when using ShinySky for Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shinysky

Running this snippet of code allows you to see an example of all the goodies that ShinySky offers:

```
if (require(devtools)) install.packages("devtools")#if not alrady installed
devtools::install_github("AnalytixWare/ShinySky")
library(shinysky)
shinysky::run.shinysky.example()
```

Of these, I'm trying to use the busyIndicator.

Unfortunately, the default position (i.e., in the middle of the app) of the image doesn't work for me. For some reason, the busyIndicator is being obscured and covered up by my ggplots.

I looked at the arguments for the busyIndicator and it looks like the only levers we have to play with are

```
text    
img 
wait
```

Of which I've played with and aren't relevant.

The ideal situation would be to simply move up it a few inches or so. Does anyone have any advice? Thanks.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you should try `withProgress` (a Shiny function) which displays a progress bar at the top, thus will not block anything

Answer (score 2):

You can use css.  A high z-index should put it in front of your plots.

```
.shinysky-busy-indicator {
  z-index: 1000;
}
```